# Functional Dependencies - how to eliminate redundant left hand side attributes?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this concept in one of my classes.

Here is an example problem. Given this table and FDs eliminate the redundant left hand side attributes:

- Table1(X, Z, Y, W, S, T, U)

  - X->Z
  - UZ->YST
  - Y->W
  - W->S

To me it looks like there are no redundant left hand side attributes, as the closure of U+ is YST and the closure of Z+ is also YST, which to me does not allow for any removal on the left hand side. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: *"the closure of U+ is YST"* Are you sure about that?

Comment: is it YSTW for U+ and Z+ because of the Y -> W and W -> S? Does that change my answer?

Comment: I think you should edit your question, and include how you calculated U+ and Z+. It might also help to include the title, edition, and page of the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

There are no redundant left-hand side attributes. When calculating the closure of U you can use only X->Z, Y->W, W->S meaning that the closure of U is U itself. By the same token, the closure of Z is Z itself. Hence, neither U nor Z is redundant in UZ->YST.

Attribute S is indeed redundant in UZ->YST since UZ determines Y, and once you know Y you also know W (Y->W) and once you know W you also know S (W->S). However, S is a right-hand side attribute and your exercise did not ask to eliminate right-hand side attributes.